# query php jsonencode result in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm echoing json with php like so:

```
 $jsonarray= array();     
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 $jsonarray["userName"]= $rs["userName"];
 $jsonarray["UserGender"]= $rs["UserGender"];
 $jsonarray["channel"]= $rs["channel"];
 $jsonarray["channelName"]= $rs["channelName"];
 $jsonarray["camonoff"]= $rs["camonoff"];
 $jsonarray["rtccam"]= $rs["rtccam"];
 $jsonarray["iswatching"]= $rs["iswatching"];
 $jsonarray["iswatchingembed"] = $rs["iswatchingembed"];
 $jsonarray["islisteningtoradio"]= $rs["islisteningtoradio"];
 $jsonarray["statusmsg"] = $rs["statusmsg"];
 $jsonarray["activity"]= $rs["activity"];

 echo json_encode($jsonarray);   
 }
```

With an ajax call i get the string like:

```
 $.get('lib/class/json.php', data, function(returnData) {
jsondata= returnData;
jsonupdateregion(jsondata);
});
```

I pass the received data to a function like:

```
function jsonupdateregion(jsondata) {
var regions = ["Lobby", "Noord-Brabant", "Groningen", "Friesland", "Gelderland", "Limburg", "Zeeland", "Overijssel", "Drenthe", "Noord-Holland",   "Zuid-Holland", "Utrecht", "Belgie", "Duitsland"];   
 var i;
  str= "";      
 for (i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
   str += regions[i]
       +  getCount(regions[i], jsondata);
  }
  console.log(str);
  }
```

The above fuction has to call the following function for every region in the array regions and return the number of occurrences

```
function getCount(regions, jsondata) {
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
    if (jsondata.channelName[i] == regions) {
        count++;
    }
 }
 return count;
}
```

The above result in a " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

When i use the json.parse on the data i get an error like: " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

The php file itself sends a header with: "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');"

What am i doing wrong here?
When i use the json.parse i get an error stating an unexpectit token

I've altered the query on the server and it's now definitly outputting valid Json according to http://jsonlint.com/ .

```
 if(isset($test)){

           $sql = 'SELECT                   
                userName,                   
                UserGender,
                UserRegion,
                channel,                
                channelName,
                camonoff,
                rtccam,
                iswatching,
                iswatchingembed,
                islisteningtoradio,
                statusmsg,
           activity

            FROM
                users'; 

       $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

       $json = array();
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           $json[]=json_encode($row);
      }
   }
   mysqli_close($mysqli);
   echo json_encode($json);

 }
```

UPDATE:

The fault was in the javascript:

Had to change:

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj.channelName[i] == regions) {
        count++;
    }
```

TO:

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].channelName == regions) {
        count++;
    }
```

And in php revert back to echoing 
    echo json_encode($json);

Comment: first of all complete quotes at Friesland", like this 
"Friesland",

Comment: Have you tried replacing `var regions = [...]` with `var regions = {...}`

Comment: The quotes is a typo here and is not the cause. Chenging the [ to { doesn't do it either. I get an error like: " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: How many records are you changing into a JSON? The fact that you are using a while loop seems there's more than one.

Comment: @mickey  there are about 100 records. You can see the result for now at http://transonly.nl/lib/class/json.php?test

Comment: Then you are outputting an invalid JSON file. Look at Michael Freund's answer. You should only be calling json_encode() once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, try to give jquery a hint, that json is sent and see, what it receives in your browser console
 (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.get('lib/class/json.php', data, function(returnData) {
    var jsondata = returnData;
    console.log(jsondata); 
    jsonupdateregion(jsondata);
}, 'json);
```

it should output an object or just a string.... eventually your php echoes some new lines or other craty things before or after the answer.
What about the charset? Is your server maybe answering in iso-something? Then js would fail decoding your jsonstring if there are some crazy chars (ü, ß, ç)

Last thing

```
$jsonarray = array();     
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jsonarray[] = $rs; //add an element.. do not overwrite it
}
echo json_encode($jsonarray);
```

Comment: The server is echoing: UTF8. The php has a content header of: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); As for the array... that gives me only [][][][]. if you want to examine the output of the php you can see it for now at: http://transonly.nl/lib/class/json.php?test

Comment: The chekc my "last thing"... you are echoing many objects, but with no array around it.... it has to look like this `[{...},{...}]` bit yours looks like this `{...} {...}`

Comment: Ok, i'm echoing the brackets now with it as you can see at  transonly.nl/lib/class/json.php?test . Again with the result:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: too much escaping... you are echoing `["{\"use...` it should be `[{"use...`, just try my second snipped in the answer

Comment: FYI the json is generated by the jsonencode in php.  echo json_encode($json); It's my guess that it outputs just what it should namely Json. :-) The json is also found valid by online jsonparsers.

Comment: whatever, please just try the second snippet.... don't echo in the loop, you last "object" should not be followed by a `,`, the other  ones should.... all objects should be encapsulated in an array

Comment: Got it working now. Indeed i was echoing the wrong json but there was also a mistake in the javascript. I took the code from somewhere else so didn't suspect it. :-) I'll update the OP .